# Errors with dependencies when build robovm locally using eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, maven, robovm

I'm following the Development guide https://github.com/MobiVM/robovm/wiki/Developer-Guide to build RoboVM locally using eclipse IDE. I have followed the steps till https://github.com/MobiVM/robovm/wiki/Developer-Guide#importing-into-eclipse without any issue and issue begins after I Imported all projects into Eclipse via their Maven poms.

When I try to fix the following errors by 'Discover new m2e connectors',

[image]

I'm getting these following errors,

[image]

Following are the above errors one by one.

1. HTTP Server 'Not Implemented': http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/.m2e/connectors/m2eclipse-tycho/0.8.1/N/0.8.1.201704211436/content.xml/content.xml - **How can I change http to https ?**

[image]

2. No repository found at http://ifedorenko.github.com/m2e-extras/. - **This is not exist now.**

[image]

3. No repository found at https://github.com/MobiVM/robovm/tree/master/plugins/eclipse.

[image]

4. Unknown Host: http://download.robovm.org/eclipse/content.xml

[image]

I have added all the following dependencies as mentioned in the development guide,

- JDK
- Maven
- CMake
- Xcode and command line tools
- IntelliJ IDEA 15 or higher, stored under /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app
- OpenSSL development libraries, install via brew install openssl on Mac OS X
- autoconf, install via brew install autoconf on Mac OS X
- automake, install via brew install automake on Mac OS X
- libtool, install via brew install libtool on Mac OS X

These are the versions I'm using,

- Mac OS: 10.15.4
- Xcode: 12.0.1
- Eclipse: 2019-03 (4.11.0)
- Robovm: https://github.com/MobiVM/robovm (master branch - 2.3.11)
- JDK: 1.8
- Maven: 3.6.3
- m2e:

[image]

I'm stuck on these errors and looking for your help please.
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I have just downloaded and fresh installed Eclipse 2020-09.
Followed guide and imported for start Eclipse plugin and then Compiler set of project.

And have not experienced this bunch of issues. More over after quick tweak of connectors and described in guide I was able to compile and run Eclipse RoboVM plugin.

Please try using up-to date version of tools.
Also try importing and solving modules one by one.